# How can I find attribute of oldest entry per user in 1:n relationship between user and entries?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

In **PostgreSQL**, I have 2 tables:

- Users (**UserID** (PK int), UserName (character varying))
- Visits (**VisitID** (PK int), *UserID* (FK Users, int), VisitDate (date), VisitReason (int), Greeting (character varying) )

1 user can visit me n times. Each visit entry has a date.

Now I want to query a **list of the users** with the `Greeting` of their oldest (`VisitDate`) visit with `VisitReason=123`. (1 row per user.) (I'm not interested in users without a relevant visit.)

What's the *easiest* way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Performance is not important. It's for a one-time task.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I can think of, is using `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` clause, with respect to `ROW_NUMBER` that ranks 1 each UserID's first date.

```
SELECT UserID, Greeting
FROM visits
WHERE VisitReason = 123
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY VisitDate)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

If you need to catch users names too, it requires an additional join (left with respect to users table) operation:

```
SELECT u.UserName, v.Greeting
FROM      users  u
LEFT JOIN visits v ON u.UserID = v.UserID
WHERE v.VisitReason = 123
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u.UserID ORDER BY v.VisitDate)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```